# how to pass through parameter in apply in R

Tags: r, parameters, lapply

`ant_list` is a list, `data` is a parameter, how can I pass through the parameter to function in `apply`, that is:

```
result<-lapply(ant_list,FUN,...)
```

how to use the parameter `data` in the `FUN`,
for example,

```
ant_list<-list(c(1,2,3,4),
               c(2,3,4,5),
               c(3,4,5,6))
data<-3

result<-lapply(ant_list,function(x){
  result_temp<-x+data
  return(result_temp)
})
```

Comment: My solution was based on the example you provided.  Otherwise, what is wrong with an anonymous function call

Comment: @akrun thank you, maybe I can find another way to solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to pass through the parameter as followed

```
ant_list<-list(c(1,2,3,4),
               c(2,3,4,5),
               c(3,4,5,6))
data<-3

result<-lapply(ant_list,function(x,data){
  result_temp<-x+data
  return(result_temp)
},data)
```